# OpenJDKのライセンスについて教えてください

Tags: java, java8, ライセンス

OpenJDKのライセンスについて調べていたところ公式サイトは難しくよく理解できず、記事の情報などを探したのですが書いている人によって全然内容が違うので正確なOpenJDKのライセンスについて詳しく教えてください。

目的は商用利用アプリの開発でOpenJDKを使いたいと考えております。

どうかよろしくお願いいたします。

### 追記

具体的には、どこまでの範囲が無償で使えるのかが気になりました。ウェブの情報にオープンソースだけどOpenJDKのソースコードにはライセンスがあるから注意が必要などと記載されていましたので初心者なのもあり訳が分からず混乱しています。

Comment: 目的は判りましたが、具体的に何が心配なのでしょうか。そこを明確にしたほうがアドバイスする側もポイントが絞りやすいと思います。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます！どこまでの範囲が無償で使えるのかが気になりました。ウェブの情報にオープンソースだけどOpenJDKのソースコードにはライセンスがあるから注意が必要などと記載されていましたので初心者なのもあり訳が分からず混乱しています。

Answer (score 1):

使用は無償です。商用利用も問題ないです。
ただ、ライセンスに則った使い方をしてないと、商用のシステムなのにライセンス違反を平気でする会社だ、と認識されます。

そのライセンスですが、OpenJDKのサイトを見ると、「GPLv2リンク例外」というライセンスとのことです。

以下私が理解している(と思っている)解釈ですが、

1. OpenJDK自体はGPLv2ライセンスなので、ライセンスに則った取り扱いが必要
2. OpenJDKのライブラリをクラスパスによってリンクするだけの場合、自社開発部分のソースコードについてはGPLv2に含まれない(ソースコードの開示等は不要)

まあ、普通の使い方をしている場合、OpenJDKについてGPLv2に則って著作権表示等はしなければいけませんが、自社開発のソースコードをどういうライセンス形態にするかは自社の自由と考えてよいです。

上記以外の使い方(OpenJDKのソースを流用したりそれをもとに拡張した機能を作ったり)をした場合はGPLv2として自社開発のソースコードも開示する必要が出てくると思います。
もし、そういった不安があるのであれば、コンピュータの著作権に詳しい法律の専門家に相談することをお勧めします。

Comment: この度はご回答を頂き誠にありがとうございます！プログラミングの勉強をする上でライセンスの事も出てきたのでよく分からずご質問させて頂きました。長文でのわかりやすい説明でありがとうございました！